# SSRS Tablix cell update based on condition for a single instance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new SSRS report in Visual Studio (VB.NET). I have prepared a report with some conditions. But I want an output like as the below image,

[image: Expected Output Will be]

I have tried like this,

[image: Report design]

Comment: So what output are you currently getting? And why are you using `Nawas` in the second calculation?

Comment: I don't think you are an SSRS report. It seems a word is missing. Can you fix your question (use "edit", to the right of "share")?

Comment: Hi Dale, Its C only. wrongly typed.

Comment: Hi Dale, The first image only i receive. The C highlighted value should updated in 3 rd Column with Negative.ex: the output like come as -280 in 3rd column and +340 in second column. Please help.

Comment: Anyone have the stuff?